# Declare qt headers as system headers with CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I use CMake with qt by saying:

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets)
```

Also, I want to use a high warning level and I want treat warnings as errors.
So I use:

```
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Werror -Wall -Wextra" )
```

However, I do not care about warnings in the libraries I use.
So, for example, to include boost I prepend `SYSTEM` in the `include_directories` call, so I do not get bothered by warnings from an external library:

```
include_directories(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )
```

But this does not work for qt, since there is no explicit  `include_directories` statement
where I could prepend `SYSTEM`.

Is there anything I could do about that?
I only found a request for that feature here:
http://www.itk.org/Bug/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=8710

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution here is to set the warning level on a per-file basis instead of the global `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. That way, only your own code gets the higher warning levels and you don't have to care about third-party code.

You can use the `COMPILE_FLAGS` property, which is available as both a [target](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#prop_tgt:COMPILE_FLAGS) and [file](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#prop_sf:COMPILE_FLAGS) property:

```
set_property(TARGET <your_target_goes_here> 
             APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS "-Werror -Wall -Wextra")
```

The disadvantage is that you have to repeat this line for every of your targets, so you might want to wrap that into a CMake function for convenience.

If you are using CMake version 3 or higher, you should use [`target_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/target_compile_options.html) instead of setting the property by hand:

```
target_compile_options(<your_target_goes_here> PRIVATE -Werror -Wall -Wextra)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another simpler solution with CMake version 3 and Qt6 (tailor it to your needs):

```
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Quick REQUIRED)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_compile_options(main PRIVATE -Werror -Wall -Wextra)

# Mark Qt6 include directories as SYSTEM include directories
target_include_directories(main SYSTEM PRIVATE ${Qt6Quick_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE Qt6::Quick)
```